# Generate a Guid only with strings that could bind to BindableName property without converting it to string from alphanumeric,to avoid duplicacy

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, guid

I want to generate a `Guid` without converting it to `string` from alphanumeric, as I have 1000's of IDs to be binded to it, without repetition. I want a perfect solution that could avoid duplicate.

My approach that is I believe will not create duplicate but not sure:

```
string guid = "panelname" + GeneratingGUID.GenerateGuid().ToString("N");


                if (!GeneratingGUID.GuidHashT.Contains(guid))
                {
                    GeneratingGUID.GuidHashT.Add(guid);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (GeneratingGUID.GuidHashT.Contains(guid))
                    {
                        GeneratingGUID.GenerateGuid();
                    }
                    guid = "panelname" + GeneratingGUID.GenerateGuid().ToString("N");
                    GeneratingGUID.GuidHashT.Add(guid);
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the code, it looks like you are generating guids until you get one that doesn't start with a number. So why not just do `var guid = "a" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`. That way it's both unique and starts with a letter.

Comment: @David actually I am using Devexpress in which I have Document panels that are programmatically generated and I have 125 different types of Document panels that could come on button click and user can open as many as he can, so if it will repeat a ID then application will crash, the method I am using now is also doing the same job. I tried that also.

Comment: But string is alphanumeric.  You don't at all answer the question from David.

Comment: @Blam I just gave him the scenario, I know Strings are alphanumeric, but what I want is string with just alphabets not numbers without repetition. I hope I made my point clear now.

Comment: Then fix the question .  You are only testing the first character.

Comment: In that I have just provided my current approach.

Comment: What is your primary goal? Just a unique ID for DevExpress? What are the restrictions? Should start with a letter? Please add answers to your question

Comment: yes in Devexpress with WPF I have to bind it with a Unique bindablename, for that I need to generate a unique key everytime a button is clicked

Comment: Seems to me you will be better off by approaching this problem the other way around: replace the numeric Id's you have with GUIDs.

Comment: @Dabbleml can I have a sample.

Comment: Is it case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code: it will never loose unique ids load as it is with MDS:

```
Guid guidValue = Guid.NewGuid();
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
Guid hashed = new Guid(md5.ComputeHash(guidValue.ToByteArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

Create a regular GUID and replace '0' with 'g', '1' with 'h' and so on. This will result in a GUID without any digits, but which is still unique.

Code to do this:

```
public static string GuidWithoutDigits()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));

    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
        sb.Replace(c, (char)(c - '0' + 'g'));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Whilst simpler than my answer, you are destroying the uniqueness of the GUID by eg changing `0` to `A`. You could simply fix that though by converting them to `G` onwards: `sb.Replace(c, (char)(c - '0' + 'G'));`

Comment: @DavidArno Well it wasn't destroying the uniqueness since I explicitly mentioned that it was case-sensitive (so a and A considered different), but I agree that we can make it unique AND case-insensitive by using G onwards (clearly a good improvement!), so I'll change the answer to include that.

Answer (score 2):

A guid is just an array of 16 bytes. You can encode those bytes in your own fashion. For example, to create a 32 character string containing just upper case letters, you could do something like:

```
public static string GuidCreator()
{
    var bytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var aByte in bytes)
    {
        var nibble1 = Convert.ToChar((aByte & 0x0F) + 65);
        var nibble2 = Convert.ToChar(((aByte & 0xF0) >> 4) + 65);
        builder.Append(nibble1);
        builder.Append(nibble2);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

It's taking each byte in turn, splitting it into the upper and lower nibbles and using those to create two characters between A - P, which are then built up into the string.

Answer (score 1):

this would give you unique string in GUID format (you may add singleton and thread safe)

```
public class UniqueIDStingOnly
{
    private static long last = 0;
    private static char[] chars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' };
    private static char[] chars2 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    public String Next()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        long cur = last;
        do
        {
            int mod = (int)cur % 6;
            sb.Append(chars2[mod]);
            cur /= 6;
        } while (cur > 0);

        ++last;

        while (sb.Length < 32) sb.Append("A");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static UniqueIDStingOnly uid = new UniqueIDStingOnly();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
        {
            string s = uid.Next();
            Guid g = new Guid(s);
            Console.WriteLine("" + a + " becomes : " + g.ToString("D"));
        }

    }
}
```